# Rounding floats to integer under bash

Tags: bash, rounding

I want to write a bash function that rounds a floating point number obtained by division of two numbers.

Here is a solution to the computation

```
n=$( echo "$1 / $2" | bc -l )
n=$( echo "($n + 0.5) / 1" | bc )
```

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022 has a section on rounding. Or do it in `bc`.

Comment: @Shawn They are doing it in `bc`.

Comment: What's wrong with your solution?

Comment: @JScoobyCed It is a bash programming question and nothing in the OP says that it is a Linux command line problem. It could be in a script file (no command line), under macOS or Windows (no Linux). This question is perfectly in scope.

Comment: I want to include the calculation in a function, so that I can use the result elsewhere.  Have seen that one just use `printf`  on the last line.  Is this how to handle return values from functions ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to round one floating point number with `bc` you will need to play with the `scale` variable (0 by default). Among other things it defines the number of digits after the decimal point of **divisions** but **not of additions**. Converting a positive floating point number to the nearest integer with `bc` can thus be obtained with an addition and a division by 1:

```
 $ printf '(%s+0.5)/1\n' "2.582908" | bc
 3
 $ printf 'scale=3;(%s+0.5)/1\n' "2.582908" | bc
 3.082
```

If you want to divide a positive floating point number by another (with, let’s say, a precision of 10 digits after the decimal point) and round:

```
 $ printf 'scale=10;tmp=%s/%s+0.5;scale=0;tmp/1\n' "2.582908" "1.265587" | bc
 2
```

If your floating point numbers can be also negative and you still want to round to the nearest integer you will need something a bit more complex:

```
$ printf 'scale=10;t=%s/%s;if(t>=0)t+=0.5 else t-=0.5;scale=0;t/1\n' "-2.582908" "1.265587" | bc
-2
```

So, your divide and round function could be based on:

```
 $ function divrnd {
   printf 'scale=10;t=%s/%s;if(t>=0)t+=0.5 else t-=0.5;scale=0;t/1\n' "$1" "$2" | bc
 }
 $ divrnd "-2.582908" "1.265587"
 -2
```

As usual, adding some control on the number and value of passed parameters, and raising errors if the function is misused, is probably a good idea.

Comment: When the number < 0 you should use `- 0.5`.

Comment: It is a tricky to check `number < 0` when the number is in floating point.

Comment: Not for `bc`. Look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add or substract 0.5 depending on the sign. For calculations with integers, first multiply by 10, add/substract 5 and next divide by 10.

```
if (( a * b > 0)); then
  echo "$(( (10 * a / b + 5) / 10 ))"
else
  echo "$(( (10 * a / b - 5) / 10 ))"
fi
```

Test with a function:

```
quotient() {
  if (( $1 * $2 > 0)); then
    echo "$(( (10 * $1 / $2 + 5) / 10 ))"
  else
    echo "$(( (10 * $1 / $2 - 5) / 10 ))"
  fi
}
b=3
for a in 11 10 -10 -11 3 -3; do
  printf -- "%s / %s = " "$a" "$b"
  quotient "$a" "$b"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

As an initial solution I have written the following function.

Have done it this way to allow both for rounding quotients using `$1` and `$2`, and for rounding of a floating point numbers using `$1`.

With regards to parsing arguments, I have written my own checks for short and long options.  Have seen programs use `--` to separate options from non-options.  I would like to avoid using `--` to separate the input numbers from the options, so the call would look as `nint $c $n` or `nint $flt`.

Does the use of `(*)`

```
nint ()
{

 iarg=0
 narg="$#"

 OLDIFS="$IFS"  # Save IFS (splits arguments on whitespace by default)
 IFS="|="       # Split arguments on "|" and "="
 set -- $*      # Set positional parameters to command line arguments
 IFS="$OLDIFS"  # Set original IFS

 while (( $# > 0  )); do
   iarg=$(( iarg + 1 ))
   case "$1" in
     # ............................................................
     ("-V"|"--version")
       printf "%s\n" "V01 Jul 2021 Wk27"
       return
       ;;
     ("-u"|"--usage")
       printf "%s\n" "-V, --version, -u, --usage, -h, --help"
       printf "%s\n" "-j NUM, --nprocs=NUM"
       return
       ;;
     ("-h"|"--help")
       printf "%s\n" "Rounds a floating point number."
       printf "%s\n" "\$@ TEXT  Sentences to print en new lines.\n"
       printf "%s\n" "Example: nint -- $mjobs $nprocs"
       printf "%s\n" "Example: nint -- $np"
       return
       ;;
     ("-v"|"--verbose")
       vb="$2" ; shift 2 ;;
     # ............................................................
     (*)
       break ;;
   esac
   shift 1  # Skip to next argument
 done

 if (($# != 1));
   fpdiv=$( echo "$1 / $2" | bc -l )
   inear=$( echo "($fpdiv + 0.5) / 1" | bc )
 else
   inear=$( echo "($1 + 0.5) / 1" | bc )
 fi

 printf '%s\n' "$inear"

}
```